# Preserving extent from the old image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I am using [PIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) 1.1.6, Python 2.5 on the Windows platform.

In my program, I am performing a point operation (changing the pixel values) and then saving the new image.

When I am loading the new and old image, they are not in the same extent. How to impose the extent of old image to the new image?

My code is:

```
img = Image.open("D:/BTC/dada_72.tif")
out = Image.eval(img, lambda x: x * 5)
out.save("D:/BTC/dada_72_Com.tif")
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's no way to guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by "extent" you mean "size" (pixels wide by pixels high), then there are several options depending on what you have as a "new" image.

If "new" is an existing image (and you want to stretch/shrink/grow the new):

```
from PIL import Image
>>> im1 = Image.open('img1.jpg')
>>> im2 = Image.open('img2.jpg').resize(im1.size)
```

If you want to crop or pad "new" that's a bit more complex...

If "new" is a new blank image:

```
>>> im1 = Image.open('img1.jpg')
>>> im2 = Image.new(im1.mode, im1.size)
```

Comment: I am creating new image by performing pixel level manipulations on the old image. And then saving the new image. When I am opening the images in the viewer it shows that old and new image are located in different locations(may be problem of projection or extent, I cannot determine)